# @Transactional doesn't open another transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to open multiple transactions​ on a method using `@Transactional` by `Spring framework`
And for some reason it's throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException : Transaction already active`

My method

```
@Transactional
Public void foo(Entity e){

      entityManager.merge(e);

      entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

      entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

  }
```

Any idea how to open multiple transaction without getting that error?

Comment: The answer is most likely related to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html maybe with `REQUIRES_NEW`

Comment: No I've tried it already... didn't worked

Comment: Well that's a shame. :(

Comment: What type of EntityManager do you have? Transaction-scope/ Extended ?

Comment: How are you exactly opening the transactions? Show us some code of what  are actually doing.

Comment: @Rjiuk entity manger factory

Comment: @DanielTaub When you use `@Transactional` you're not suppose to handle the transaction on your own. That's already handled by the transaction interceptor code added to the method by Spring. Perhaps that's the reason why you get the exception.

Comment: Can you post a code sample of your method and the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: How do you create EntityManager?

Comment: @Rjiuk entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo so how I should commit the transaction?

Comment: @DanielTaub The transaction commits when the `@Transactional` annotated method ends (returns). Why would you want the logic of a single business method to commit multiple times? The business method represents one atomic transaction.

Comment: @DanielTaub The `@Transactional` annotation you add to your method is to ask Spring to enrich the method with transaction semantics. Spring will add a begin transaction before your method and will commit and rollback after it ends. You don't need to add anything there. Just use the entities and Spring will do the rest.

Comment: @Andreas but it never opens me a new transaction

Comment: @DanielTaub Not true. The fact that `begin()` throws exception saying `Transaction already active` means that a new transaction *was* started when the `@Transactional` annotated `foo` method was entered. Don't call `begin()` and don't call `commit()`. Transaction is managed by Spring.

Comment: @Andreas but without to use begin() spring throws exception of transaction not active

Comment: @DanielTaub Can't respond to that, since you didn't share stacktrace of that error and the code that causes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing what the Spring `@Transactional` annotation means. When you use that annotation you're asking Spring to enrich your method invocation with transaction semantics.

You may want to take a look at the [TransactionAspectSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html) class, more specifically the method [invokeWithinTransaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html#invokeWithinTransaction-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.InvocationCallback-) which is the place where all the magic happens for your transactional methods.

You will see there that before your code is invoked, a new transaction is created, then your code is executed, and after that, either a commit or rollback happens. In other words, Spring's aspect controls the transaction for you.

All these magic needs some configuration for it to happen: you need to make sure that Spring finds your `@Transactional` methods and enrich them. To do so you need to add a piece of configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

And of course you need to define a transaction manager that can be used by your transactional methods. It seems you're using JPA so a [JpaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) makes sense in this case:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
            <property name="prepareConnection" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test-api"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.company.humanresources</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg name="emf" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Finally, if you want to gain access to the entity manager being used by your current transaction, you can do something like:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "test-api")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Transactional
public Department addDepartment(String name) {
   EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(emf);
   Department department = new Department();
   department.setName(name);
   em.persist(department);
   return department;
});
```

Once more, Spring will control the transaction semantics around your transactional method. You must also take into account that the default Spring behavior only works with public methods.

Comment: But why when I used entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); it didn't recognized there is a transaction but when using EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(emf); it's works?

Comment: The answer to your question is hidden inside the code of the classes I recommended you to read in my answer. The Spring code is open source, if you take the time to read it you'll find your answer yourself. But to give you some help, the `TransactionAspectSupport` will invoke the `JpaTransactionManager` method called `doBegin`, which if you read, you will notice it creates a new `EntityManager` for your transaction. That's the one you must use in your Spring-controlled transaction. If you create a new one on your own, Spring has no knowledge of it. It is not the one Spring is using.